# Changing short date format in Ubuntu

Tags: datetime, ubuntu

How do I change the system-wide short date format in Ubuntu?  For example, Thunderbird is showing dates in the DD/MM/YY format, and I would like to change it to MM/DD/YY or YYYY-MM-DD.

The best information I can find so far is in this thread:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=193916

Edit: I want to change the system-wide date format, so that all my applications use this new date format.

Comment: I've written a [mini Howto](http://ccollins.wordpress.com/2009/01/06/how-to-change-date-formats-on-ubuntu/) on this. It's not as easy as I had expected, but shouldn't pose too many problems.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on AskUbuntu.

Answer (score 6):

- Install and launch "dconf Editor", navigate to com -> canonical -> indicator -> datetime.
- Set the value of `time-format` to `custom`.
- Customize the Time & Date format by editing the value of `custom-time-format`, e.g. set it to `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S` for "2017-12-31 23:59:59" format.
- Re-login to see effect of the changes.

You can also do this via a command in terminal:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.datetime time-format 'custom'
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.datetime custom-time-format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

Source: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/12/time-date-format-ubuntu-panel/

Comment: Get error with the command `No such schema “com.canonical.indicator.datetime”`

Comment: This doesn't exist on my system. The only thing inside of `com/canonical` is `unity`, there is no indicator. I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 with Gnome.

Answer (score 3):

How to do this in 2017 with [Ubuntu 16.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_.28Xenial_Xerus.29) (Xenial Xerus) is described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/session-formats.html). Cut/Paste follows below in case that site goes away:

**Change date and measurement formats**

You can control the formats that are used for dates, times, numbers, currency, and measurement to match the local customs of your region.

- Click the icon at the very right of the menu bar and select System Settings.
- Open Language Support and select the Regional Formats tab.
- Select the region that most closely matches the formats you'd like to use. By default, the list only shows regions that use the language set on the Language tab.
- You have to log out and back in for these changes to take effect.
  Click the icon at the very right of the menu bar and select Log Out to log out.
- After you've selected a region, the area below the list shows various examples of how dates and other values are shown. Although not shown in the examples, your region also controls the starting day of the week in calendars.

Answer (score 1):

Thunderbird uses the system's date format, and that format depends on the system's locale settings. You have two options:

1. modify the system locale, the instructions are in the forum thread you linked above, or
2. set `LC_TIME` to a locale that uses the format you want. The [article](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Date_display_format) linked by [Craig H](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159950/changing-short-date-format-in-ubuntu#159963) suggests `en_DK`.

Comment: Except that it doesn't work - it will use a British date format instead of the ISO 8601 defined in en_DK. The closest I have found is [this documented bug](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Date_display_format), but it doesn't seem to apply.

Answer (score 1):

The instructions [here](https://ccollins.wordpress.com/2009/01/06/how-to-change-date-formats-on-ubuntu/) worked for me to create a custom locale based on `en_US`. Then Thunderbird showed the date/time format how I want (I prefer YYYY-MM-DD over MM/DD/YY).

Some time later, the date/time format in Thunderbird changed back to what was set in `en_US` (MM/DD/YY), because I had inadvertently set $LC_ALL to `en_US.UTF-8`. So, I `sudo gedit /etc/environment` and changed `LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"` to `LC_ALL="custom.UTF-8"`. Finally, Thunderbird is showing the dates how I want them.